# List the monitors physically connected to remote computer (make/model details)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, display

If I were sitting in front of the computer I could run `xrandr --query` in terminal but this doesnt tell me the make/model (at least i know something is connected) but while remote (using ssh) I receive "Can't open display".

I need to be able to run a command via SSH that will not only tell me what monitors are connected to what ports but also find the monitors specific information like make/model.

Comment: Im getting a bit closer... xrandr will work through SSH if i define the display
xrandr -d :0.0 -q

and /var/log/Xorg.0.log will show the make/model of my local machine but does not show the make/model of connected HDMI tv to a raspberry pi
grep -e "(*connected*)" /var/log/Xorg.0.log